# Class template partial specialization equivalence

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

When do two different class template partial specialization declarations match?

In the code below there are two partial specialization declarations:

- `S<constrain<T,has_accept_>, void>`
- `S<constrain<T,has_visit_>,  void>`

`constrain` is an alias template that equals to `T` but is constrained using an `enable_if` trick with the second parameter as a concept.

GCC considers that these two partial specialization are *different* but Clang and MSVC consider that they are *equivalent* and thus reject the code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

template<class T,class=void>
struct has_accept
  :false_type{};
template<class T>
struct has_accept<T,void_t<decltype(declval<const T&>().accept())>>
  :true_type{};

template<class T,class=void>
struct has_visit
  :false_type{};
template<class T>
struct has_visit<T,void_t<decltype(declval<const T&>().visit())>>
  :true_type{};

//pre c++17 clang/MSVC fix: default argument of template 
//   used as template template argument not implemented yet
template<class T> using has_accept_ = has_accept<T>;
template<class T> using has_visit_ = has_visit<T>;

template<class T,template<class> class TT,class=enable_if_t<TT<T>::value>>
using constrain = T;

template<class T,class=void>
struct S
  :false_type{};
template<class T>
struct S<constrain<T,has_accept_>,void>  // (1)
  :true_type{};
template<class T>
struct S<constrain<T,has_visit_>,void>  // (2)
 :true_type{};  // ==> MSVC and Clang: error (2) redefines (1)
```

I cannot find anything in the standard that would specify partial specialization equivalence. [[temp.type]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type) does not seem to apply here.

What does the standard say about partial specialization declaration equivalence?

Comment: Please specify compiler version numbers.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano On the tests I performed on compiler explorer the behavior was independent of the version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [CWG 1980](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1980), "Equivalent but not functionally-equivalent redeclarations":

> In an example like
>
> ```
> template<typename T, typename U> using X = T;
> template<typename T> X<void, typename T::type> f();
> template<typename T> X<void, typename T::other> f();
> ```
>
> it appears that the second declaration of `f` is a redeclaration of the first but distinguishable by SFINAE, i.e., equivalent but not functionally equivalent.
>
> Notes from the November, 2014 meeting:
>
> CWG felt that these two declarations should not be equivalent.

This is still an active issue. gcc's behavior is more in line with the desire that these be different. [[temp.alias]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.alias#2.sentence-1) and [[temp.alias]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.alias#3.sentence-1) are the relevant transparency rules:

> When a *template-id* refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by substitution of its *template-arguments* for the *template-parameters* in the *type-id* of the alias template.
>
> However, if the *template-id* is dependent, subsequent template argument substitution still applies to the *template-id*.

which are in conflict here. In the simplified example from the issue, `X<T, U>` is *equivalent* to `T` - which means both declarations just have return type of `void` - but substitution still applies, which doesn't exactly mean they're *equivalent*.

Comment: [The rules about (functionally) equivalent declarations](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link) are related to function template declarations. Why do these rules apply to class partial specializations?

Comment: @xskxzr I'm not sure I understand the premise of question.